# Matching Brackets in TeX output

Tags: math-mode, color, pdf, brackets

Is there any ways or features to make pdf-files using one of TeX systems so that when I move the cursor to one of brackets (either open or closed brackets) in pdf, then the bracket and the other matching bracket are changed in its color, e.g., in red?

For example (see below), I want in pdf document, when I put my cursor on the first squared bracket, then its color and the color of the matching square bracket (in this case, the last one) are turned into other color. When there is no matching bracket, then it would be changed in other color than that in matching case.

(Ex) [(a + 3(b-c)) + 2*7]

Answer (score 1):

This probably *could* be done with PDF and JavaScript (for switching the color of the brackets), but I know of no (La)TeX package for that. And it would need JavaScript in the PDF viewer. And it will probably be quite fragile.